# Are table lookups, like get_table_rows, included in CPU/NET resource calculation?

Tags: table, cpu, resources, bandwidth

If a smart contract includes user data, would our smart contract be charged CPU/NET resources to do lookups on those tables, or is it only charged for transfers and actions etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not charged for any [RPC getter API calls](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/reference).  If you're not forced to sign the transaction, then there's no way to know which account to charge.

You're charged if you're changing state or pushing data to the chain.